# Set a word under a word in UILabel/UITextView Swift

Tags: swift, string, uilabel

I'm trying to understand ways to implement the placement of a word under a word in a UILabel or UITextView.
I know that there is an offset on the y axis in the attributes of the string, but not on the x axis. Therefore, I did not find a solution in this.

Just in case, the code that changes the position on the Y axis. Its disadvantage is also that it shifts the neighboring word to the right.

```
extension String {
func setSuperscript(text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    let foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: text)
    
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    
    if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
        attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: foundRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: -10, range: foundRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: foundRange)
    }
    
    return attributedString
}
```

}

It looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?